# Haskell, can i call function without IO output working with monads?

Tags: haskell, io, monads

Why i can't do this?
Its forbidden the use of 'do' in this question :/
How i can call *words* in my list and at same time result an IO?
Thanks.. this is my actual code :/

```
main :: IO()
main = 
     putStr "Name of File: " >>
     getLine >>=
     \st ->
    openFile st ReadMode >>=
    \handle ->
        hGetContents handle >>=
        \y ->
        words y >>=
        \strings ->
            strings !! 1 >>=
            \string->
                 putStr string
```

[Edit] Solution :

```
main :: IO()
main = 
     putStr "Name of File: " >>
     getLine >>=
     \st ->
    openFile st ReadMode >>=
    \handle ->
        hGetContents handle >>=
        \y ->
        return (words y) >>=
        \strings ->
            return (strings !! 1) >>=
            \string->
                 putStr string
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `return (words y)` instead of just `words y`. `return` wraps a pure value (such as the `[String]` that `words` returns) into a monad.

From your wording, it sounds like this question is homework. If so, it should be tagged as such.

Answer (score 6):

(This doesn't directly answer the question, but it will make your code more idiomatic and thus easier to read.)

You are using the pattern `\x -> f x >>= ...` a lot, this can (and should) be eliminated: it is (mostly) unnecessary noise which obscures the meaning of the code. I won't use your code, since it is homework but consider this example (note that I'm using `return` as suggested by the other answer):

```
main = getLine >>= 
         \fname -> openFile fname ReadMode >>= 
           \handle -> hGetContents handle >>= 
              \str -> return (lines str) >>= 
                \lns -> return (length lns) >>= 
                  \num -> print num
```

(It reads a file name from the user, and then prints the number of lines in that file.)

The easiest optimisation is the section where we count the number of lines (this corresponds to the part where you are separating the words and getting the second one): the number of lines in a string `str` is just `length (lines str)` (which is the same as `length . lines $ str`), so there is no reason for us to have the call to `length` and the call to `lines` separate. Our code is now:

```
main = getLine >>= 
         \fname -> openFile fname ReadMode >>= 
           \handle -> hGetContents handle >>= 
              \str -> return (length . lines $ str) >>= 
                \num -> print num
```

Now, the next optimisation is on `\num -> print num`. This can be written as just `print`. (This is called [eta conversion](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Eta_conversion)). (You can think about this as "a function that takes an argument and calls `print` on it, is the same as `print` itself"). Now we have:

```
main = getLine >>= 
         \fname -> openFile fname ReadMode >>= 
           \handle -> hGetContents handle >>= 
              \str -> return (length . lines $ str) >>= print
```

The next optimisation we can do is based on the [monad laws](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monad_laws). Using the first one, we can turn `return (length . lines $ str) >>= print` into `print (length . lines $ str)` (i.e. "creating a container that contains a value (this is done by `return`) and then passing that value to `print` is the same as just passing the value to `print`"). Again, we can remove the parenthesis, so we have:

```
main = getLine >>= 
         \fname -> openFile fname ReadMode >>= 
           \handle -> hGetContents handle >>= 
              \str -> print . length . lines $ str
```

And look! We have an eta-conversion we can do: `\str -> print . length . lines $ str` becomes just `print . length . lines`. This leaves:

```
main = getLine >>= 
         \fname -> openFile fname ReadMode >>= 
           \handle -> hGetContents handle >>= print . length . lines
```

At this point, we can probably stop, since that expression is much simpler than our original one (we could keep going, by using [`>=>`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad.html#v:-62--61--62-) if we wanted to). Since it is so much simpler, it is also easier to debug (imagine if we had forgotten to use `lines`: in the original `main` it wouldn't be very clear, in the last one it's obvious.)

In your code, you can and should do the same: you can use things like [sections](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Section_of_an_infix_operator) (which mean `\x -> x !! 1` is the same as `(!! 1)`), and the eta conversion and monad laws I used above.

Comment: Thank you  for the complete explanation. I applied the optimizations to my code, and reduce it more than ten lines ehhehe. Your post was very useful for me.. thanks again :)